# ubuntu18.04 error found when loading /etc/profile

Tags: ubuntu-18.04

My system opreater is ubuntu18.04,and when i use two screens,and log in my account,it not showing my desktop,instead of the error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FH7C8.jpg)
But when i shut down the second screen,it will be working with no problem.

Comment: try using `autorandr` as i described in this AskUbuntu answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1376245/8 voting to close as off-topic here though.

Comment: my dear mechanical_meat,i try to do the thing which you described,but when i reboot my computer, it doesn't work,problem still exists